# Error javax.swing.JFrame cannot be cast to pantallaPrincipal

Tags: java

Estoy intentando pasar datos de una pantalla a otra y me tira el siguiente error, no se como arreglarlo.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
javax.swing.JFrame cannot be cast to pantallaPrincipal

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JFrame cannot be cast to pantallaPrincipal
at dialogAlta.<init>(dialogAlta.java:23)
at dialogAlta$2.run(dialogAlta.java:251)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
atjava.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Aqui el codigo que donde me tira el error.

```
private pantallaPrincipal p;

public dialogAlta(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    p = (pantallaPrincipal)parent;
    initComponents();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si quieres pasar datos tendrias que pasarle el parent como parametro a PantallaPrincipal para eso debes modificar el constructor de pantallaPrincipal

```
public class PantallaPrincipal {
    private JFrame frame;

    public PantallaPrincipal(JFrame  frame){
        this.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Ahora en dialogAlta() colocas:

```
p = new PantallaPrincipal(parent);
```

Pd:Las clases en JAVA empiezan con la primera letra en mayúscula

Comment: Me sirvió, ya esta arreglado